# Electron Chromium Inspector

Tags: javascript, electron

I have a very basic Electron application whith a simple package.json like this:

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "main.js"
}
```

and the main.js file like this:

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')
const path = require('path')
const url = require('url')

// Keep a global reference of the window object, if you don't, the window will
// be closed automatically when the JavaScript object is garbage collected.
let win

function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  win = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600})

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  win.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
    protocol: 'file:',
    slashes: true
  }))

  // Open the DevTools.
  win.webContents.openDevTools()

  // Emitted when the window is closed.
  win.on('closed', () => {
    // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
    // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
    // when you should delete the corresponding element.
    win = null
  })
}

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on('ready', createWindow)

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  // On macOS it is common for applications and their menu bar
  // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})

app.on('activate', () => {
  // On macOS it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
  // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
  if (win === null) {
    createWindow()
  }
})
```

But when I start the app the chromium's inpector apear in the screen together with my index.html page. Why the inspector apear automtically?

Answer (score 3):

It isn't technically called the "Inspector", but the "DevTools", short for "Developer Tools" on Chromium. The reason it's opening on app startup is because you are opening the DevTools with this line:

```
win.webContents.openDevTools()
```

`BrowserWindow.webContents` is documented [here](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/web-contents.md#contents.openDevTools), with the description of `openDevTools`:

> **`contents.openDevTools([options])`**
>
> Opens the devtools.

Remove this to stop the DevTools from opening.